# Can you a call a Sub that has an argument with a button?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to call the following sub with a button from my excel sheet but it doesn't appear in the list when you try to assign a macro. I also call it from a bigger macro, in which case I don't want to show the "Finished" message box. Hence I have the DontShowMsgBox boolean argument.

```
Sub InteriorDumbCopyExport(DontShowMsgBox as Boolean)

'do stuff...

If DontShowMsgBox Then
    MsgBox "Finished."
End If

End Sub
```

It's when I add the argument in that I can no longer see it in the list. Is there an easy way around this?

I want to call the sub directly as I have to call it from a shape so can't use an ActiveX button. I haven't found anything in my searching so far but feel there must be a solution, otherwise what is the difference between a function with an argument and a sub with an argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed do that. In the Assign Macros dialog, simply type the name of the macro and the argument, all enclosed in single quotes. For example:

'InteriorDumbCopyExport True'

Note however that this can cause problems if your workbook is saved as an xlsb file (I don't know why).

In this particular case though, I'd just make the argument optional and default to whichever value you want the shape to use. Then you just use the macro name in the Assign Macros dialog without adding a parameter.

Comment: Thank you mate, that's really helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Simply call your button `sub` with another `sub`:

```
Sub test() 'call with your button
Call InteriorDumbCopyExport(DontShowMsgBox as Boolean)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to know the source of your `DontShowMsgBox`. As a public variable, you could set it in front of executing the macro and then directly use it within having no arguments for the call itself.
In any module:

```
Dim DontShowMsgBox As Boolean
```

And if you only need it for debugging then make it a `Const` which will only be true if you want it to.

Answer (score -1):

For a FORM control that's normal behaviour as you cannot assign a Sub depending on parameters as the button wouldn't know which parameter to hand over (for a  similar reason you can't link functions to buttons), whereas an ActiveX button would create its own Sub (e.g. `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()`) within the code space of the worksheet it appears.

So use a Sub without parameters for the button to call, within the sub determine the actual condition of `DontShowMsgBox` and call another Sub doing the job into which youdeliver this parameter.

Comment: FYI, you *can* pass parameters, and link Functions, with shapes.

Comment: aha!?! ... will check ... sounds interesting ... thanks for making aware - I perhaps would never have tried that myself